# Getting error in access of google calendar api

Tags: php, google-api

I'm trying to access the google calendar through google api but getting error like this

```
Type: Google_Service_Exception

Message: Error calling GET 
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo: (401) Invalid Credentials

Filename: /opt/lampp/htdocs/CI/application/third_party/google-api-
php/src/Google/Http/REST.php

Line Number: 110
Backtrace:

File: /opt/lampp/htdocs/CI/application/third_party/google-api-
php/src/Google/Http/REST.php
Line: 62
Function: decodeHttpResponse

File: /opt/lampp/htdocs/CI/application/third_party/google-api-
php/src/Google/Task/Runner.php
Line: 174
Function: doExecute

File: /opt/lampp/htdocs/CI/application/third_party/google-api-
php/src/Google/Http/REST.php
Line: 46
Function: run

File: /opt/lampp/htdocs/CI/application/third_party/google-api-
php/src/Google/Client.php
Line: 593
Function: execute

File: /opt/lampp/htdocs/CI/application/third_party/google-api-
php/src/Google/Service/Resource.php
Line: 240
Function: execute

File: /opt/lampp/htdocs/CI/application/third_party/google-api-
php/src/Google/Service/Oauth2.php
Line: 173
Function: call

File: /opt/lampp/htdocs/CI/application/libraries/Googleplus.php
Line: 62
Function: get

File: /opt/lampp/htdocs/CI/application/models/Googlecalendar.php
Line: 83
Function: getUser

File: /opt/lampp/htdocs/CI/application/controllers/Main.php
Line: 17
Function: getUserInfo

File: /opt/lampp/htdocs/CI/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

I'm totally blank why m getting this error.I have also created credentials form google console but still not removed.

Please help me to get this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> (401) Invalid Credentials

Has three possible causes.

1. Means that the client id and client secrete that you are using for your application are incorrect.
2. Also check Google developer console make sure that you have both product name and an email address set up in Google Apis Console.
3. If this is a web application make sure that you are only trying to login with the user that created the project on Google developer console until your project has been though the approval process.